# CRM Plugin: how to update associated contacts' addresses when you update account address

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm using `Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016` on-premise version.

I have an `"account" entity` which has associated `"contacts".` When the current `"account" entity's "address"` is updated, I want all the associated contacts addresses to be updated with that address.

I want to do this in a plug-in which runs on the `"account"` entity when you update the address. When you do so, ALL the associated contacts have their address updated to that address.

I've done a bit of searching for this, but there's nothing out there which shows the ADDRESS getting updated. The examples out there typically show, for example, a phone number being updated. What makes the address more complicated is that the addresses are stored in an address entity, so I think I have to get an `addressId primary key` of some kind and put that in each of the `associated contacts address FK field.` I've no idea how and can't find any similar examples.

> Does anyone have a snippet of code that will go into the plugin?

[NB I'm planning on putting it in the `public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)` method in the plugin code.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the id of a contact's address when updating it. Two types of addresses are already incorporated in the contact entity. They are typically used for postal and visit addresses. The address field names are prefixed with `address1_` and `address2_`. So, just set these fields like this on the contact entity:

```
contact["address1_line1"] = "John Doe";
```

A plugin could look like this:

```
public class AccountPlugin : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        var orgService = factory.CreateOrganizationService(null);
        var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        Entity account = context.PostEntityImages.First().Value;

        var query = new QueryExpression("contact");
        query.Criteria.AddCondition("accountid", ConditionOperator.Equal, context.PrimaryEntityId);

        var result = orgService.RetrieveMultiple(query);

        foreach (Entity contact in result.Entities)
        {
            contact["address1_line1"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("address1_line2");
            orgService.Update(contact);
        }
    }
}
```

Register it on the post update message on entity account and add a post entity image to the step.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying that point. What I'm actually after is the code that will go into the plugin. In other words, how to a get a list of the applicable contacts for that account (which I can then loop through doing as you suggest).

Comment: You can query the system using `QueryExpression`s. LINQ queries are also supported. I added an example. More information can be found on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks very much, Henk. That's perfect - it does the job admirably! Accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Henk Van Boeijen's excellent answer above, I post the following code (which is Henk's code posted into my plug-in).

Here is the code for a plugin which will update all of the addresses for all of the contacts connected to an organisation, when you update the organization's address.

Note that in this example, the Organization entity has been called Account.

This is to help anyone in future who needs to accomplish this.

```
public class UpdateContactAddresses : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // Create a tracing instance to log progress of this plugin.
        ITracingService tracing = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

        try
        {
            // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
            IPluginExecutionContext pluginExecutionContext = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            // Obtain the organization service reference.
            IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(null);

            if (pluginExecutionContext.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && pluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                // Obtain the target entity from the input parameters.
                Entity account = (pluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity);

                // Verify that the target entity represents an account. If not, this plug-in was not registered correctly.
                if (account.LogicalName != "account")
                {
                    tracing.Trace("This entity is not an Account entity. It is likely that this plug-in was not registered correctly (was an incorrect \"Primary Entity\" selected? It should be an Account entity).");
                    return;
                }

                var query = new QueryExpression("contact");
                query.Criteria.AddCondition("accountid", ConditionOperator.Equal, pluginExecutionContext.PrimaryEntityId);

                var result = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
                tracing.Trace("The QueryExpression found " + result.TotalRecordCount.ToString() + " associated contacts.");

                foreach (Entity contact in result.Entities)
                {
                    tracing.Trace("Updating contact " + contact.ToString() + " address...");
                    contact["address1_line1"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("address1_line1");
                    contact["address1_line2"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("address1_line2");
                    contact["address1_line3"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("address1_line3");
                    contact["address1_city"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("address1_city");
                    contact["address1_county"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("address1_county");
                    contact["address1_postalcode"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("address1_postalcode");
                    contact["address1_country"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("address1_country");
                    service.Update(contact);
                    tracing.Trace("Contact " + contact.ToString() + " address updated.");
                }
            }

            tracing.Trace("Completed execution of plugin " + this.GetType().Name + ".");
        }
        catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in plugin " + this.GetType().Name + ".", ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tracing.Trace("An error occurred executing plugin " + this.GetType().Name + ".");
            tracing.Trace("\t\tError: " + ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }

    }

}
```